# Send More Search Parameters in Struts2 jQuery Grid

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

First time I am using Struts2 jQuery Grid for AJAX data table.

I have also some filter parameters exactly above table. How to send those params?

```xml
<s:select name="par1" list="filesList" label="Select File" accesskey="MyKey" id="par1"/>
<s:select name="par2" list="fileDataStatus" label="Select Status"/>
More Like StartDate And EndDate.

<s:url var="remoteurl" action="searchCSVDataList" escapeAmp="false">
     <s:param name="par1" value="%{par1}"></s:param>
     <s:param name="par2" value="%{par2}"></s:param>
</s:url>

<sjd:grid id="gridtable"
                caption="Customer Examples"
                dataType="json"
                href="%{remoteurl}"
                pager="true"
                gridModel="gridModel"
                rowList="10,15,20"
                rowNum="15"
                rownumbers="true">
                <sjd:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" width="200px;"/>
                <sjd:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" />
    </sjd:grid>
```

How to send those par1 and par2 in JqGrid Action? I have also tried with `<s:url>` tag but its not working.

Comment: You can send parameters in the URL that's true, why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is The Perfect Answer. I just Discovered it.

You need to create form. and put all fields which you want to send with request.

And Give that form id to jqGrid as formIds.

```
<form id="myForm">
        <s:select label="Select a month" 
              headerKey="-1" 
              headerValue="Select Month"
              list="#{'1':'Jan', '2':'Feb', '3':'Mar', '4':'Apr'}" 
              name="yourMonth" 
              value="2" 
              id="selectedMonth"/>
              <input type="text" name="par1" value="OOOOOOO1"/>
              <input type="text" name="par2" value="OOOOOOO2"/>

              <input type="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="myAjaxFunction();"/>    
    </form>
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable" >
        <s:param name="par1">Kshitij</s:param>
    </s:url>

    <sjd:grid id="gridtable"
                formIds="myForm"
                caption="Customer Examples"
                dataType="json"
                href="%{remoteurl}"
                pager="true"
                gridModel="gridModel"
                rowList="10,15,20"
                rowNum="15"
                rownumbers="true">
                <sjd:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" width="200"/>
                <sjd:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" />
                <sjd:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" />
    </sjd:grid>
```

Comment: If i use hidden fields, how user will know that i have to write something here to filter below table.

Comment: can you pls post the java code related to it? Because I have been trying to implement search in struts2 jQuery grid and still couldnt get it working.